# Proving a lemma about an extending $R$ module with no $M$-singular direct summands in "Extending modules" (1994)

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

I'm reading this book:

> Dung, N. V., Van Huynh, D., Smith, P. F., & Wisbauer, R. (1994). Extending modules (Vol. 313). CRC Press.

In the proof of Lemma 11.1, there is a part that I can not understand:

Let M be a module and $X \subset M$ be a direct summand and consider any exact sequence:

$0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow  M \rightarrow  X \rightarrow 0$.

My question is: If $N$ is a direct summand of $M$ that contains $K$, is the module $N/K$ isomorphic to a direct summand of $X$?
The book states: Yes  but it dos not explain why.

Here is the Lemma.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello: titling your question "question about <generic term>" is a great way to make your question fade into the background and become ignored.  Strive to be as specific as possible, even if it's the problem statement itself. I've improved it for you this time.  You should also consider replacing the image in your post by actually writing out what it says.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it.